# java.lang.Runtime Exception?

Tags: java, android, file, gridview

When loading all files which contains images and videos from sdcard and, shown it in gridview this is what my scenario so while working with files am getting runtimeexception.

This is my code

MainActivity class

```
AsyncTaskLoadFiles myAsyncTaskLoadFiles;
    ImageAdapter myImageAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
        myImageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
        gridview.setAdapter(myImageAdapter);

        myAsyncTaskLoadFiles = new AsyncTaskLoadFiles(myImageAdapter);
        myAsyncTaskLoadFiles.execute();
```

Asyncloadfiles:

```
        File targetDirector;
        ImageAdapter myTaskAdapter;

        public AsyncTaskLoadFiles(ImageAdapter adapter) {
            myTaskAdapter = adapter;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            String ExternalStorageDirectoryPath = Environment
                    .getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();

            String targetPath = ExternalStorageDirectoryPath + "/test/";
            targetDirector = new File(targetPath);
            myTaskAdapter.clear();

            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            File[] files = targetDirector.listFiles();
            for (File file : files) {
                publishProgress(file.getAbsolutePath());
                if (isCancelled())
                    break;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
            myTaskAdapter.add(values[0]);
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            myTaskAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

    }
```

ImageAdapter:

```
    private Context mContext;
    ArrayList<String> itemList = new ArrayList<String>();

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    void add(String path) {
        itemList.add(path);
    }

    void clear() {
        itemList.clear();
    }

    void remove(int index) {
        itemList.remove(index);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return itemList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return itemList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null)
        { // if it's not recycled, initialize some
            // attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);

        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        Picasso.with(mContext).load(itemList.get(position)).into(imageView);


        return imageView;
    }
```

can you please tell me what is the mistake in the above code.

This is the logcat error.

```
11-15 11:07:38.760: E/AndroidRuntime(779): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
11-15 11:07:38.760: E/AndroidRuntime(779): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
11-15 11:07:38.760: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
11-15 11:07:38.760: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
11-15 11:07:38.760: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
11-15 11:07:38.760: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
11-15 11:07:38.760: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
11-15 11:07:38.760: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
11-15 11:07:38.760: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
11-15 11:07:38.760: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
11-15 11:07:38.760: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
11-15 11:07:38.760: E/AndroidRuntime(779): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-15 11:07:38.760: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at com.example.picasagrid.MainActivity$AsyncTaskLoadFiles.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:54)
11-15 11:07:38.760: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at com.example.picasagrid.MainActivity$AsyncTaskLoadFiles.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
11-15 11:07:38.760: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
11-15 11:07:38.760: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
11-15 11:07:38.760: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  ... 5 more
```

Comment: Can you add the exact error message and stacktrace to your question?

Comment: posted my error too..

Comment: @Haritha_90 do you see the `Caused by...` in the stack trace? Will that help you find the problem?

Comment: What's line MainActivity.java:54?

Comment: Does `targetDirector` have non-null value ?

Comment: yes sherb i saw which is pointed at for each loop

Answer (score 0):

for **IO operations** always use **try catch** because your address to the file might be wrong or the directory might not exist and things like these  and here it is because your file doesn't exist or the address to it is wrong